# Backslashes being removed and unable to set Solc in windows 10

Tags: go-ethereum, windows, solc

I've installed Geth on win 10 and I'm trying to link solc but I'm not sure why the backslashes are being removed?  How can I get past this error?

```
> admin.setSolc("C:\Program Files\Ethereum\solc")
exec: "C:Program FilesEthereumsolc": file does not exist
    at InvalidResponse (<anonymous>:-81662:-48)
    at send (<anonymous>:-156322:-48)
    at setSolc (<anonymous>:-133322:-48)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add two blackslashes where you have one. This is because the `\` character is an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

The following output shows how the `\` is treated:

```
> console.log("C:\\Program Files\\Ethereum\\solc")
C:\Program Files\Ethereum\solc
```

If the above does not work, try adding `.exe` at the end of the `solc` filename and confirm that your `solc.exe` is located at `C:\Program Files\Ethereum\solc.exe`.

---

**EDIT 15/06/2016 suggested by `@jeff balough`**

or

```
admin.setSolc("C:\\Ethereum 0.9.41\\Release\\solc.exe")
```

yea